# New iTerm2 tab displays ‘brew: command not found’ after updating PHP although brew is installed and included in PATH

Tags: bash, homebrew, iterm

I’m at the end of my rope here and hope you guys & gals can help out.

I use the package `bash-completion` via `brew`, and, after this morning, I get this message when I open a new iTerm2 tab:

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

Afterwards, I can execute `brew` without errors.

I have this `if` block in my `.bashrc` file, which gets sourced by `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -r "/opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]
then
  source "/opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
fi
```

All of a sudden this isn’t enough, which is confusing because if always have been working until this morning. I installed the latest version of PHP this morning, run `brew doctor` and added `/opt/homebrew/sbin` to my `$PATH`, removed PHP and orphaned packages but nothing seems to change the message I get.

**If I remove the `if` statement above the message disappears.**

I have no clue how and why and was wondering if someone can help me out.

`echo $PATH`:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/john/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

`type brew`:

```
brew is /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

`ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/brew?`:

```
-rwxr-x---@ 1 john  admin   4.9K May 22 07:03 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

- Paste of my .bashrc: [link](https://pastebin.com/CXxUrbxk)
- Paste of my .bash_profile: [link](https://pastebin.com/TRpFJAQ8)

Comment: If type works, shouldn‘t brew as well?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/brew`?

Comment: @nohillside: Indeed, and it does work. It’s just weird that every new tab I open in iTerm2 shows the message `-bash: brew: command not found`.

Comment: @jaume: Output: `-rwxr-x---@ 1 john  admin   4.9K May 22 07:03 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew`

Comment: if it only occurs once within a new tab, there is something in your startup files which calls brew before the path is set correctly.

Comment: `.bashrc` is sourced for every non-login, interactive shell *first*.  This the tab(s) you open *after* the first one.  `.bash_profile` is sourced on the login interactive shell (first one).  *Where* in `.bash_profile` do you source `.bashrc`?  Can you post your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` to pastebin or similar?

Comment: I believe your she-bang is incorrect in .bashrc.  Type `which bash` and compre the very first line to that output.

Comment: @Allan: do you mean the first line? That is just a comment I put into the paste to signal the file. It’s not in my `.bashrc`. But I checked anyway and it looks good.

Comment: The shebang is the line that starts with `#!`.  Does that path match what you got in `which bash`?

Comment: @Allan: it does match.

Comment: The shebang I only used if the filename I used as the command on the command line. So not used I startup files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when you try to run the bash_completion.sh file brew is not on your $PATH.

The fix is to move the line where you set $PATH to be above the test for bash_completion.sh file ie your .bashrc has these commands as

```
# Prepend brew and $HOME/bin to $PATH
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:""/opt/homebrew/sbin:""$HOME/.bin"":$PATH"
 

# Bash completion
if [ -r "/opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]
then
  source "/opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
fi
```

Comment: This solved my issues instantly. Thank you **all** for helping me.

Comment: `/opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` is just a wrapper for `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_3/etc/bash_completion`. Interestingly enough, `brew` seems to get called from neither. But hey, if it works, great :-)

Comment: @nohillside: Indeed, I’m glad that pesky message disappeared but still scratch my head as in how.

Comment: I just tried with a shell without homebrew in the path. Sourcing `/opt/homebrew/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` worked without a problem. Makes me wonder what kind of side-effect the edit described in the answer had.

Comment: @qwewrerhtjykuhlj Do you have a `~/.bash_completion`?

Comment: @nohillside - What you say makes sense - nothing in that .bashrc or .bash_profile should be calling brew

Comment: @qwewrerhtjykuhlj If you are open for some more experiments: Can you undo the change and check whether the problem reappears in a new tab? If it does, can you (in the current shell) set/export the path to `/bin:/usr/bin`, run `/bin/bash -lixc exit 2>&1 >/tmp/bash.log` and upload the log to pastebin?

Comment: @nohillside: I don’t have a .bash_completion in my $HOME. I ran the bash line you asked me to but the log showed up empty. There was output however: [paste](https://pastebin.com/QRngLaaU).

Comment: Yeah, my bad, should have been `>/tmp/bash.log 2>&1`. But I don't see the error in the log, did it actually happen?

Comment: @nohillside: no worries. Yeah I got the error again: `-bash: brew: command not found`.

Comment: @qwewrerhtjykuhlj there is no call to brew in the output?! I‘m totally confused here.

Comment: What is the command that iTerm calls . It is the profile and the general tab command

Comment: iTerm2 command: nothing. It’s just a login shell. Terminal, the default app, same.